# Merging two datasets summing a shared column

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

I have a situation similar to this one:

I have two datasets, this one:

| from | to | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | 2 |
| a | b | 3 |

and this one:

| from | to | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | 3 |
| a | b | 4 |

Now, I want to merge the two, keeping "from" and "to" variables the same, since they are exactly the same BUT, meanwhile, SUMMING the frequency.

This is what we should get:

| from | to | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | 5 |
| a | b | 7 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With base R we can use `aggregate` + `rbind`

```
> aggregate(frequency ~ ., rbind(df1, df2), sum)
  from to frequency
1    a  a         5
2    a  b         7
```

Or, we can use `xtabs` + `as.data.frame` + `rbind`

```
> as.data.frame(xtabs(frequency ~ ., rbind(df1, df2)))
  from to Freq
1    a  a    5
2    a  b    7
```

## Data

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(from = c("a", "a"), to = c("a", "b"), frequency = 2:3), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-2L))

> dput(df2)
structure(list(from = c("a", "a"), to = c("a", "b"), frequency = 3:4), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-2L))
```

Comment: Cool answer that's not on cited in the canonical question

Answer (score 4):

One cool (`dplyr`) option is using the `powerjoin` package:

```
library(powerjoin)
power_left_join(df1, df2, by = c("from", "to"), conflict = `+`)
```

**Result**:

```
   from to frequency
1:    a  a         5
2:    a  b         7
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do with `data.table`

```r
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.frame(from = c("a", "a"), to = c("a", "b"), frequency = c(2, 3)) |> setDT()


df2 <- data.frame(from = c("a", "a"), to = c("a", "b"), frequency = c(3, 4)) |> setDT()


df1[df2, on = .(from, to), 
    frequency := x.frequency + i.frequency]
```

**output**

```
     from     to frequency
   <char> <char>     <int>
1:      a      a         5
2:      a      b         7
```

Comment: How can I use the last code when I already have two dataframes? Without using fread, so

Comment: You could set your data.frame as data.table like `setDT(df1)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
df1 <- data.frame(from = c("a", "a"), to = c("a", "b"), frequency = c(2, 3))


df2 <- data.frame(from = c("a", "a"), to = c("a", "b"), frequency = c(3, 4))

# Merge and sum frequencies
merged_df <- bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
  group_by(from, to) %>%
  summarise(frequency = sum(frequency))
```

print(merged_df)

```
  from  to    frequency
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
1 a     a             5
2 a     b             7
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` we can just use two steps

```
df1 <- data.frame(from = c("a", "a"), to = c("a", "b"), frequency = c(2, 3))
df2 <- data.frame(from = c("a", "a"), to = c("a", "b"), frequency = c(3, 4))

inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("to","from")) %>% 
  mutate(frequency = frequency.x + frequency.y)
```